# return type in stream operator overloading

Tags: c++, inputstream

The purpose of program is to take input, assign those values to the members of the class and display the output, with the input and output operation being done by overloading stream operators.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class MyClass {
int x, y;
public:
  MyClass(int i, int j) { 
     x = i; 
     y = j; 
  }

  friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &stream, MyClass ob);
  friend istream& operator>>(istream &stream, MyClass &ob);
 // friend void operator<<(ostream &stream, MyClass ob);
 // friend void operator>>(istream &stream, MyClass &ob);
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream &stream, MyClass ob)
{
  stream << ob.x << ' ' << ob.y << '\n';

  return stream;
}

istream& operator>>(istream &stream, MyClass &ob)
{
  stream >> ob.x >> ob.y;

   return stream;
}

int main()
{
MyClass abt(30,23);
cin>>abt;
cout<<abt;
return 0;
}
```

In the example, if data is taken from input stream 'cin' and the values are assigned inside the function, why should 'istream' be returned back. I have seen all tutorials return stream in operator overloading function. What is the purpose of return value?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> In the example, if data is taken from input stream `cin` and the values are assigned inside the function, why should `istream` be returned back?

This is done to allow "chaining".

The operator takes its two parameters from both sides of `>>`. The stream comes from the left, and the variable comes from the right. When you do this

```
cin >> x >> y;
```

the first expression `cin >> x` is on the left of the second expression, which means that the result of `cin >> x` becomes `... >> y`'s input stream. That is why the operator needs to return the same input stream that has been passed into it.

Answer (score 2):

How do you suppose the following works?

```
stream >> ob.x >> ob.y;
```

That's exactly the same as:

```
(stream >> ob.x) >> ob.y;
```

So what's the value of `stream >> ob.x`?

Answer (score 2):

> *"What is the purpose of return value?"*

The purpose is, that these operations can be chained in statements like

```
MyClass abt(30,23);
int y;

cout << abt << endl;
         // ^^^^^^^

cin >> abt >> y;
        // ^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

`cout` and `cin` are linked with each other through `<iostream>` the child class of `istream` and `ostream`. Now as we are about to overload operators as a global functions because overloading as a member the operator must be the member of the object on the left hand side. Also to make the function of the generic streams we have to pass the references and not values. So we have to opt for overloading them with friend function.
Hence:

```
istream & operator>>(istream &din,vector &vtemp)
```

Now the `din` will work similar to `cin` as `din` has a reference to `cin`. Now using `din` we scan the data-members of the object. After scanning we have to chain them (streams). So reference must be returned to `cin`.