# Why use a reference when returning an ostream class?

Tags: c++, class, reference

The full code looks like this:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

class Point {
double x;
double y;
public:
Point();
Point(int x, int y);
void setPoint(int x, int y);
int getX(void)const;
int getY(void)const;
Point operator + (const Point & point);
Point& operator=(const Point& point);
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Point& point) {
 os << point.getX() << " ," << point.getY();                    
 return os;
}

Point::Point() {
x = y = 0;
}
Point::Point(int x, int y) {
this->x = x;
this->y = y;
}
void Point::setPoint(int x, int y) {
this->x = x;
this->y = y;
}
int Point::getX(void)const {
return this->x;
}
int Point::getY(void)const {
return this->y;
}
Point Point::operator+(const Point& point) {
Point result(this->x + point.getX(), this->y + point.getY());
return result;
} 
Point& Point::operator=(const Point& point) {
this->x = point.getX();
this->y = point.getY();
return (*this);
}
int main() {
Point a(1, 2);
cout << a << endl;
}
```

In the following part

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Point& point) {
 os << point.getX() << " ," << point.getY();    
 return os;         
}
```

If the return type is ostream, a red line appears. I am not sure what the difference between return type is ostream & and ostream. I'd appreciate it if you explained

*For reference, I forgot to return os, so I edited the post

Comment: The issues with slicing aside, returning by value is making a copy. Think about what it means to copy a stream -- copying a file stream might make sense since there is `dup()`. But what would it mean to copy a stream backed by a TCP stream? Maybe there are types of streams that can't be copied... so we can't allow it in the general case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would return an `ostream` then you would have slicing. In case the passed `os` was an `ofstream` then the returned `ostream` would only be the `ostream` part of the `ofstream` and not the full `ofstream`. When returning by reference you don't have slicing and don't lose information about the full type of the stream.

Comment: Thanks! I think I lack understanding of streams. I'll study more. Could you give me some reference material?
Thanks for the reply

Comment: @bongbong, Go no further than [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45172025/about-stdostream-constructor?rq=1)

Answer (score 2):

The ostream object cannot be copied as the copy constructor of ostream object is deleted.
That is why one needs to pass the ostream object by reference.

Pro tip: Ever wondered why we need to return `ostream&` if it was already passed by reference?

Comment: @Werner Henze's answer is better though... accept that if you want

Comment: Can you explain why you should return by reference even when passed by reference?

Comment: @bongbong, checkout [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28710021/return-type-in-stream-operator-overloading) link